# Custom Magento Theme Not Showing

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, theme

I have installed a magento theme (Milano), which installs at:

`app/design/frontend/default/milano`

I want to customize this theme and I have set up new theme directories:

`skin/frontend/default/mycustomtheme`
and
`app/design/frontend/default/mycustomtheme`

with a varied css at

`skin/frontend/default/mycustomtheme/css/styles.css`

In System->Configuration->Design I have changed the Skin to mycustomtheme and left everything else as the default milano, but it still won't show the customisation to the css on my store.

I have refreshed the cache and reindexed the data.

I have also checked the `System > Design` and there is no design themes listed there either.

Comment: I think, `milano` theme is not obeying the standard code of magento. like `hardcoding the skin paths` instead of using `getSkinUrl()`.. it is just a thought. I could be wrong though.

Comment: What is the content of `Current Package Name` into the Package tab in Configuration > Design?

Comment: @SylvainRayé `Current Package Name` is `default`

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize 4 theme fallbacks via `System > Configuration`.  You should set it up as follows:

[image]

This way, when Magento looks for a theme file (design or skin), it will look through the package/themes and use whatever it finds first (in this order):

1. `default/mycustomtheme`
2. `default/milano`
3. `default/default` (even though it's not specified, Magento will always use the default theme of a package)
4. `base/default` (this theme is always included last)

Other things to check:

- Change store scope and make sure your settings are making it down to the store view
- Check var/log/.  It's possible that your files aren't readable/visible/misplaced

Answer (score 1):

## Configuration

Package name should be `default`

Theme default should be `milano`
Skin should be `mycustomtheme`.

The other inputs might be blank or `milan` or `mycustomtheme` this doesn't matter.

## Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head and head.phtml

Check wether `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` was rewritten. If yes have a look on `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getCssJsHtml()`

Check the content of `/app/design/frontend/default/milan/template/page/html/head.phtml` there should be only a `<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>` and no hard coded links or anything as @Mr_Green described